# How do i create an Tag object in android?

Tags: android, nfc, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've been trying to find a way to instantiate the Tag object. I'm trying to do this so that i can simulate various types of Tags.

Does anyone know how to get an instance of UltraLight object using

```
Tag tag = ?????
UltraLight obj = UltraLight.get(tag);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the NFC app example for ICS source code, we can find some code such as:

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putParcelable(Ndef.EXTRA_NDEF_MSG, ndefMsg);
extras.putInt(Ndef.EXTRA_NDEF_MAXLENGTH, 0);
extras.putInt(Ndef.EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE, Ndef.NDEF_MODE_READ_ONLY);
extras.putInt(Ndef.EXTRA_NDEF_TYPE, Ndef.TYPE_OTHER);
Tag tag = Tag.createMockTag(new byte[] { 0x00 },
    new int[] { TagTechnology.NDEF },
    new Bundle[] { extras });
```

Code for this `createMockTag` method is following:

```
public static Tag createMockTag(byte[] id, int[] techList, Bundle[] techListExtras) {
    // set serviceHandle to 0 to indicate mock tag
    return new Tag(id, techList, techListExtras, 0, null);
}
```

Maybe this could help.

Comment: Thanks,.I'm gonna try it and see...from the top of my mind, i cant understand how it might work cuz there is no constructor like that for the Tag class right?

Comment: I did check out the source code. The function cannot be called! :/

Comment: You're right. Maybe another idea: when using the Tag class, we can use its constant named [CREATOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#CREATOR). This one returns an object [Creator<Tag>](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html). Such an object has a method [createFromParcel(Parcel)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator.html#createFromParcel%28android.os.Parcel%29) which can help.

Comment: I tried that out also, since that is the only option that is left, but i dont think i'm sending in the right values for the Tag object to get successfully created. Just a pointer, i couldn't find anything called
    Ndef.EXTRA_NDEF_CARDSTATE or any of those other Ndef.* constants that you had used.