# How do I mock an NFC Tag for an in-app developer tool?

Tags: java, kotlin, nfc, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

I am trying to mock an NFC Tag with an in-app developer mocking tool. The current implementation uses reflection and is targeting API 27. Migrating to API 28 with AndroidX, the method `createMockTag` is not found. I notice that it's `public static` in the Android code, but is annotated with `@Hide`, meaning that I can't access it. I have found a way, however, to create a Tag from a Parcel, but I have not found anywhere a simple way to do it. I can create my own Parcelable class, but when calling `in.readInArray(...)` in the constructor, it asks for a parameter that I don't have. I will attach what it looks like know and what I'd like it to look like.

This is a big issue because we need to mock NFC Tags, but there doesn't seem to be a way to access the method. And I've also tried to copy the `Tag.java` class into my project, but it can't access certain seemingly-internal classes such as `INfcTag` and the enums in `TagTechnology`. Has anyone else come across this and can please help me? Thank you.

```
// Tag mockTag = Tag.CREATOR.createFromParcel(); // I'd like to create one here
Method createMockTag = Tag.class.getMethod("createMockTag", byte[].class, int[].class, Bundle[].class);     
scanIntent.putExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG, (Tag) createMockTag.invoke(Tag.class, tagId, new int[]{}, new Bundle[]{}));
```

Here are links I've looked at:

- https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidParcelable/article.html
- https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-parcelable
- [How do i create an Tag object in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428276/how-do-i-create-an-tag-object-in-android)
- [Identifying NFC tag ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322424/identifying-nfc-tag-id)
- https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=android+9+nfc+not+working&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8
- https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&biw=1080&bih=923&ei=68ijXMnoDoHisAXPjLzQCA&q=public+static+Tag+createMockTag%28byte%5B%5D+is%2C+int%5B%5D+techList%2C+Bundle%5B%5D+techList+Extras%29+%7B&oq=public+static+Tag+createMockTag%28byte%5B%5D+is%2C+int%5B%5D+techList%2C+Bundle%5B%5D+techList+Extras%29+%7B&gs_l=psy-ab.3...107084.107084..107212...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.rfrM415Sx7o
- https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.html
- https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/28/changes.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.Creator
- And probably several more whose tabs I've closed or navigated away from.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to copy the code from the original, that's not how mocking works.  If this specific method has been marked with @Hide it likely means that its being deprecated.  That likely means there is an alternative to this method in API 28+.

The @Hide is likely a result of them not being able to fully deprecate it just yet, but will likely in the future.  Here is the current reference - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/package-summary.

In general though, say your using Mockito - https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#2 - just stub the mock.
For stubbbing static methods, looks like there are a couple of threads out there - for the actual feature request: https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/1013

And workaround: [Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito) not sure how relevant the workaround is anymore (its somewhat old).

Comment: The original poster is my yournger brother.  So, I was providing a high level answer as well as specifics.  But it answers the question completely.  You mock by using Mockito, whether its NFC or not is irrelevant.  Also a bit of coaching / mentoring, and chatting / discussing an issue via SO.